# call a function on the top most directive while passing a parameter using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So the story is like this:

I have a controller (full.js) which is attached to a view (full.html).

The full controller is injecting a directive (person.js / person.html) into the full.html view, which itself (person.js) injecting another directive to person.html (called files.js).

now, i want that when you click on a file which is populated by the 2nd level directive file.js, it will call a function on the full.js controller.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to accomplish this. If the directives are ALWAYS used in this hierarchy, then you can build that expectation into the directive definitions. For an example of that approach, see the tabbed pane example on the front page of the Angular site (http://angularjs.org/). By putting `require: '^tabs'` in the definition of the `pane` directive, `tabsCtrl` can be referred to directly within the `pane` controller.

Another, more portable way to accomplish this is to use Scope.$emit to emit a message that will propagate up the scope hierarchy. Listen for it from the full controller (using Scope.$on), and then trigger whatever you need to trigger.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope